# is MST a Steiner tree?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I am a little bit confused about MST and Steiner tree? Is an MST a steiner tree?? and suppose we are given a weighted undirected connected graph G = (V,E) and S ⊆ V  is the smallest subtree of an MST of G that contains all the vertices from S a Steiner tree of S in G?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, here's an example:

\begin{array}{rcl}
\blacksquare &\stackrel{2}\leftrightarrow & \blacksquare  \\
{\Tiny{1}}\updownarrow& &\updownarrow \Tiny{1} \\
\bullet &\stackrel{1}\leftrightarrow & \bullet  \\
\end{array}

The unique minimum weight spanning tree contains the three edges with weight $1$.
However, a Steiner tree joining the two black squares uses a single edge for a total weight of $2$ instead of $3$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: So a Steiner tree is a MST for a subset of the edges in the graph while a MST connects all the edges. Is this right? (Atleast in the context of networks aka real world graphs)

Comment: @VenkiPhy6 Not really, in particular it can contain vertices that are not terminals. Steiner tree is a MST for the subgraph that contains all the terminals and minimizes its MST cost. In other words, you take all the subgraphs that contain all the terminals (and perhaps some other vertices too), you calculate for each the MST and then take the one that has the smallest cost.

Answer (score 1):

MST and Steiner trees are relatively close concepts since the only difference is that in a Steiner tree you are allowed to add nodes.

However an MST needs not to be a Steiner tree, there are a lot of counterexamples, for example take a equal sided triangle of vertices A,B,C with a fourth vertex D in the middle. Then AB,BC is an MST for A,B,C, however the Steiner-tree AD,BD,CD is smaller.

Concerning your second question, this depends on whether you fix the MST. For a fixed MST, the above is a counterexample. However if you take the smallest subtree out of the subtrees of all MST of subsets of vertices of G then in fact, this is true.

In fact a Steiner tree $T\subset E$ of S is an MST but not of S but of the set $V(T)$ of all vertices belonging to edges in T. So in the above example AD,BD,CD is an MST for A,B,C,D. If a tree T would be a Steiner tree for S, but not an MST for V(T), then there is a smaller MST for V(T), which then in turn would be a smaller Steiner tree for S, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Steiner trees can be viewed as a generalization of MST's.
A MST must includes all vertices of $V$, whereas a Steiner needs only to include the vertices of a given $S \subseteq V$ (though it can include more than $S$).  So it all depends on $S$.

If $S = V$, then indeed a MST is a Steiner tree for $S$.  If $S \subset V$, then a MST could be a Steiner tree for $S$, but not necessarily.

As for the second question, that would be too easy - considering MST is polynomial but finding a Steiner tree is NP-Hard.  Consider this simple example of $K_3$ with vertices $a,b,c$ and all edge weights to $1$.  Take the MST $T$ that consists of the edges $\{ab, bc\}$.  Now, say we want to find a Steiner tree for $S = \{a, c\}$.  The smallest subtree of $T$ that contains $S$ is actually $T$, of total weight 2.  But the Steiner tree for $S$ is just the edge $ac$.